# Sending XML to URL in PHP (without cURL)

Tags: php, xml, post

Trying to send the following XML data to URL below.

```
$xml="<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Job>
  <Name>Set-up - ".$client_name."</Name>
  <Description></Description>
  <ClientID>".$accountantid."</ClientID>
  <StartDate>".$start_date."</StartDate>    
  <DueDate>".$due_date."</DueDate>  
  <TemplateID>".$templateid."</TemplateIDr>

</Job>";

$createjob_url="https:<url>apiKey=[apikey]&accountKey=[accountkey]";

$stream_options = array (
        'http' => array (
                'method' => "POST",
                'header' => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
                'content' => $xml
        )
);
$context=stream_context_create($stream_options);
$response=file_get_contents($createjob_url, false, $context);

echo "<p>".$response."</p>";
```

The response should come out 'OK', but its just blank.

The debug.log has the following error.

```
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(https:<url>?apiKey=[apikey]&accountKey=[accountkey]): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
```

I noticed the URL changes the '&' to '&'. If I put the url directly into the browser, it doesnt work, however if I remove 'amp;' it gives me the OK response.

But then if I remove from the code 'false, $context' e.g. `file_get_contents($createjob_url)`, the response comes back 'OK', so the URL is fine.

I am using Google App Engine hence unable to use cURL.

I assume it has something to do with my stream options? Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So looks like my issue was a couple of small things.

For the particular URL I was parsing to, I didnt need to have the XML tag, so removed `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>`

They also wanted the content type as xml, so changed it to `'header' => "Content-type: text/xml"`

Once I got these two sorted, all worked well :)